# Apache HAWQ production usage

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hawq

I'm not sure where else to ask this question, so I'll ask it here, as I think this might serve as a nice reference for future users who might have a similar question.

Are there any known production usages of Apache HAWQ (http://hawq.incubator.apache.org/)? I would like to compare this service with others such as Presto, Spark, Impala, etc. But I haven't come across any real-world usages of it other than nice-looking benchmarks. And finally, if you have used this personally, what have been your experiences with it?

Comment: Spark kinda stands out in your list there. The others are both a database and a SQL framework. Spark is a general distributed programming library with no persistent database within its project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no independent doc for apache hawq. But the community is moving the doc from pivotal hdb to apache hawq. And the docs links on the page is linking to the hdb docs (http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/211/hdb/index.html). You can refer to this one first and you can find incubator-hawq-docs projects at https://github.com/apache/incubator-hawq-docs.

Besides, if you do not know where to ask questions, you could subscribe the dev and user mail list, send email to dev-subscribe@hawq.incubator.apache.org / user-subscribe@hawq.incubator.apache.org to subscribe and send emails to dev@hawq.incubator.apache.org / user@hawq.incubator.apache.org to ask questions.